# create a circular stream in Dart

Tags: stream, dart

I try to write a chat application to chat with a computer. The user can write a message and gets a response of the computer. A chat history might look like this:

```
user: Hi
computer: Hello
user: What's your name?
computer: Bot
...
```

My circular stream based design is inspired by the ideas of [Cycle.js](http://cycle.js.org/). I've got a stream of user messages, which get transformed to a stream of computer messages, which are in turn the input of the user message stream:

```
    |----> user message stream ---->|
    |                               |
transform                       transform
    |                               |
    |<-- computer message stream <--|
```

This code already works:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  cycle(computer, user);
}

typedef Stream<T> Transform<T>(Stream<T> input);

void cycle(Transform aToB, Transform bToA) {
  var aProxy = new StreamController.broadcast();
  var b = aToB(aProxy.stream);
  var a = bToA(b);
  aProxy.add('start'); // start with user
  aProxy.addStream(a);
}

Stream<String> user(Stream<String> computerMessages) {
  computerMessages = computerMessages.asBroadcastStream();
  computerMessages.listen((message) => print('computer: $message'));
  return computerMessages.map((message) {
    stdout.write('user: ');
    return stdin.readLineSync();
  });
}

Stream<String> computer(Stream<String> userMessages) {
  var messages = <String, String>{
    "Hi": "Hello",
    "What's your name?": "Bot"
  };
  return userMessages.map((m) => messages.containsKey(m) ? messages[m] : 'What?');
}
```

There is only one problem. You need a start value to get a circular stream running. Therefore, I put this line in my function `cycle`:

```
aProxy.add('start'); // start with user
```

Actually, this logic belongs into my function `user`, since `cycle` shouldn't know the initial value(s). Moreover, I don't like to print the initial value. It should only trigger the user input stream. Thus, I changed `cycle` and `user`:

```
void cycle(Transform aToB, Transform bToA) {
  var aProxy = new StreamController.broadcast();
  var b = aToB(aProxy.stream);
  var a = bToA(b);
  aProxy.addStream(a);
}

Stream<String> user(Stream<String> computerMessages) {
  computerMessages = computerMessages.asBroadcastStream();
  computerMessages.listen((message) => print('computer: $message'));
  var requestInput = new StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  requestInput.add('start'); // start with user
  requestInput.addStream(computerMessages); // continue on computer response
  return requestInput.stream.map((message) {
    stdout.write('user: ');
    return stdin.readLineSync();
  });
}
```

But with this change my application terminates immediately with no message in stdout. What's wrong?

Comment: I didn't try to fully understand what the code does. I suspect you need to make `aProxy`, `a`, and `b` (or at least one of them)  a top-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Create a normal instead of a broadcast `StreamController` in `user`:

```
Stream<String> user(Stream<String> computerMessages) {
  computerMessages = computerMessages.asBroadcastStream();
  computerMessages.listen((message) => print('computer: $message'));
  var requestInput = new StreamController<String>();
  requestInput.add('start'); // start with user
  requestInput.addStream(computerMessages); // continue on computer response
  return requestInput.stream.map((message) {
    stdout.write('user: ');
    return stdin.readLineSync();
  });
}
```

Even though I found a solution, I sadly can not really explain what's the problem with a broadcast `StreamController`. `null` is successfully added by `requestInput.add(null);` but strangely neither `requestInput.addStream(computerMessages);` completes nor events of `computerMessages` are added to `requestInput`. Thus, `requestInput` is closed and the application terminates. I would appreciate if someone could provide further explanation.

Comment: The reason the original didn't work is that you add the `"start"` string before you do the `map` call. Broadcast streams don't buffer events (their subscriptions do while they are paused, but the stream itself doesn't), so since there are no subscribers at the time, the event is just dropped.